# Is there a way I can see all currently running Google Apps Scripts?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have lots of GSheets with google apps scripts in them. Is there a way I can see which ones are currently running on my account?

Comment: Do you mean all the scripts or just those that are time triggered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If "currently running" means "have a trigger that runs them periodically or under certain conditions, then the answer is to go to Script Editor, select Edit -> All my triggers.

The triggers not associated with the currently opened script will appear in light grey, which makes them look as if they are inactive items that can't be edited. And indeed, they cannot be edited from here - but they can be *deleted* from this menu by clicking `x` on the left.